# Android image upload to server has different size than original. why?

Tags: php, android, image, upload

I have an android app that uploads a photo to a server using HttpClient and HttpPost. The problem is that the uploaded photos are consistently twice the size or more than the original on my android device. For example a photo on my device has a size of (699 KB), when I upload that photo to the server its new size is (1935 KB).

both images have the same resolution and they are both JPEG files.

Comment: have you looked at what's IN the files? just because the name's the same doesn't mean something didn't change. e.g. your .jpg got turned into a .bmp or something like that. or even a bunch of extra garbage got appended.

Comment: It looks like you might be encoding your image into base64 and then you don't decode it. Post your code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The picture is compressed into a PNG and uploaded to the server, then it is renamed as a JPEG. Here is the code that compresses the picture. <Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);> I am testing it now after changing PNG to JPEG, to be sure it is about the original size.

Comment: PNG takes more space then JPG so there you are. Why are you compressing to begin with?

Comment: Why am I compressing to begin with... That is a good question. I am not the original programmer so I am still trying to figure out what the other guy did. Here is the sequence of events.

Comment: the ByteArrayOutputStream that contains the compressed image transformed to a byte array `.toByteArray` this is placed in a `ByteArrayBody` finally this is added to a `HttpMultipartEntity` which is sent via a `postRequest.setEntity()`.